# Doing Age Calculations via OOP

Tags: php, oop

I have to add age calcuation functions to a class file via OOP in PHP. The input is in mm/dd/yyyy format.

The code I have sorta works, but it's not giving me the right results. How do I fix it?

```
<?php 

class user {

public $firstName;
public $lastName;
public $birthDate;
public function setfirstName($firstName) {
    $this->firstName = $firstName;
}
public function getfirstName() {
return $this->firstName;
}

public function setlastName($lastName) {
$this->lastName = $lastName;
}
public function getlastName() {
return $this->lastName;
}

public function setbirthDate($birthDate) {
$this->birthDate = $birthDate;
}
public function getbirthDate() {
return $this->birthDate;
}

public function getAge() { 
return intval(substr(date('mmddyyyy') - date('mmddyyyy', strtotime($this->birthDate)), 0, -4));
}

}

?>
```

I would also like to be able to add ten years and subtract ten years.

Comment: Have you read [the `date()` docs](http://us1.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)? Your format strings of `mmddyyyy` are probably not doing what you expect them to. PHP would expect `mdY` for a date in that format.

Comment: Not sure why people are downvoting. Votes are not for the quality of code but question.

Comment: For example `date('mmddyyyy')` returns the string `0606171713131313`

Comment: @LoïcFaure-Lacroix votes are for whatever you want them to be for.

Comment: PHP date formats !== MS Excel date format masks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [DateTime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class to easily manipulate dates. I have put the `$dateFormat` outside of the method because you could also use that to validate your input in `setBirthDate` if you saw fit.

```
protected $dateFormat = 'm/d/Y';

public function getAge()
{
    // Create a DateTime object from the expected format
    return DateTime::createFromFormat($this->dateFormat, $this->birthDate)

        // Compare it with now and get a DateInterval object
        ->diff(new DateTime('now'))

        // Take the years from the DateInterval object
        ->y; 
}
```

Note that I used `m/d/Y` for the date format because as per the comments, the `mm/dd/yyyy` does not do what you expect. For example, Y is a 4 digit year.

Ignore the ugly syntax, it's just so I could explain what each bit does.

Comment: This won't necessarily give the right result.

Comment: You should remove the first solution, it's wrong. Take one person born in november and the current time. Taking the current time (june), it will give you +1 year than it actually is.

Comment: Fair point. Could calculate whether or not the current day and month is beyond that of now but not worth it when DateTime and DateInterval do it fine. Will remove the first.

Answer (score 0):

First, I would change the setBirthday method to ensure that the saved field is a date. Inside the getAge, you'd have to do simple calcule without having to convert something to a string to a int or whatever.

get the current time minus the birthdate and you should get the right answer. I can't unfortunately give more details because I've left the php world for while but it should be like this.

Check this out: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-diff.php

The first parameter should be the current time and the second parameter the birthday

```
public function getAge() {
  $now = new DateTime();
  $interval = $this->birthDate->diff($now);
  return $interval->format('%Y');
}
```

The setBirthdat should look like this:

```
public function setbirthDate($birthDate) {
  $this->birthDate = new DateTime($birthDate);
}
```